# How to convert <img> element to Nextjs <Image> component

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I've been writing Nextjs for a while but some of the image components are still in `<img>` tag like this. (based on TailwindCSS)

```
    <div className="relative">
                        <div className="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div className="flex-1 bg-transparent" />
                            <div className="w-full flex-1 bg-black" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6">
                            <img
                                className="relative rounded-lg"
                                src="/images/somephoto.png"
                                alt="screenshot"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The current code shows the image in the center of the page with a relative position.
I've tried to convert the tag into the Next `<Image />` component though it is hard to keep the styling since we need to specify `width` and `height`.

I would like to know the conversion tips between `<img>` and Next `<Image>` if any. (Appreciate it if you have an idea for the above case example)

Comment: What if you just replace the current `img` with nextjs <image> component and add the styling to the outer div?

Comment: thanks looks like it worked! I just need to add `fill` prop in the Image component tho. I was struggling before but after updating Next version to 13, seems like working naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your current code is working correctly without adding any additional staying to the `img` tag, you can just replace it with the `<Image />` component from next.js

```
<div className="relative">
  <div className="absolute inset-0 flex flex-col" aria-hidden="true">
    <div className="flex-1 bg-transparent" />
    <div className="w-full flex-1 bg-black" />
  </div>
  <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6">
    <Image
      loader={myLoader}
      src="me.png"
      alt="Picture of the author"
      layout='fill'
    />
  </div>
</div>;
```